# Treeview is not recognizing desired height

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I've got a treeview that is ignoring my desire to create a more compact view.  The treeview extends well below the height of my page, so I'm trying to get it to sit inside a panel or div that's roughly 300px.  No matter where I place the div or panel tags, it doesn't seem to change the height and the treeview continues until it's at the end of the data.  Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

## asp.net:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // It is important to place this JavaScript code after ScriptManager1
   var xPos, yPos;
   var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

   function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
       if ($get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>') != null) {
           // Get X and Y positions of scrollbar before the partial postback
           xPos = $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').scrollLeft;
           yPos = $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').scrollTop;
       }
   }

   function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
       if ($get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>') != null) {
           // Set X and Y positions back to the scrollbar
           // after partial postback
           $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').scrollLeft = xPos;
           $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').scrollTop = yPos;
       }
   }

   prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
   prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
</script>

 <asp:Panel ID="FPanel" runat="server" Height="300px">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="300px">
<div style="height:300px">
                <asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewAccts" runat="server" ShowLines="true" PopulateNodesFromClient="false" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged1" Height="118px" ShowExpandCollapse="true" Font-Size="X-Small" Width="645px" NodeIndent="10" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="DarkBlue" ExpandDepth="0">
                    <NodeStyle VerticalPadding="1" 
                                Font-Names="Courier" 
                                Font-Size="8pt" 
                                NodeSpacing="0" 
                                HorizontalPadding="5" 
                                BorderStyle="Solid"
                                BorderColor="DarkCyan"
                                BorderWidth="1"
                                BackColor="White"
                                Width="640">
                    </NodeStyle>        
                </asp:TreeView>   
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTreeselect" runat="server" Enabled="False" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="xCoordHolder" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="yCoordHolder" runat="server" />
</div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  For anyone interested, there is a property of the panel that does this called "ScrollBars".

I changed

```
 <asp:Panel ID="FPanel" runat="server" Height="300px">
```

to

```
 <asp:Panel ID="FPanel" runat="server" Height="300px" ScrollBars="Vertical">
```

After adding this, I was able to remove the div tag completely and everything worked as expected.